# How to send headers to a JMS message

Tags: java, jms

I am trying to add headers to a JMS message. The headers being `eventType`, `messageId`, `correlationId` and `messageStamp`. This is my queue sender method:

```java
public void messageSentInQueue(String queueName, Message payload)
            throws JMSException {

    if (!MessageQueueConfigs.userName.isEmpty() || !MessageQueueConfigs.password.isEmpty() || !MessageQueueConfigs.brokerUrl.isEmpty()) {
        try {
            connection = ActiveMQConnection.makeConnection(MessageQueueConfigs.userName, MessageQueueConfigs.password, MessageQueueConfigs.brokerUrl);
            connection.start();
            // create a Session
            session = connection.createSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
            System.out.print("what is session" + session);

            // create the Queue to which messages will be sent . If the Queue is not there it will be auto created
            Queue queue = session.createQueue(queueName);
            // create a MessageProducer for sending messages
            messageProducer = session.createProducer(queue);
            TextMessage textMessage = session.createTextMessage(payload);
            System.out.println("message to sent" + payload);
            messageProducer.send(payload);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            connection.close();
        }
    }
}
```

How can I send headers along with the payload?

Comment: Please read: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question) --- Are you using by any chances the smallrye connector for ActiveMQ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you are using JMS, the way to go is the message properties. You define them with the `setXxxProperty` family of methods. Quoting from the [Message Javadocs](https://javaee.github.io/javaee-spec/javadocs/javax/jms/Message.html):

> ##### Message Properties
>
> A Message object contains a built-in facility for supporting application-defined property values. In effect, this provides a mechanism for adding application-specific header fields to a message.

So, go ahead, create your message, e.g.: `TextMessage textMessage = session.createTextMessage(payload);` and then set headers as:

```java
textMessage.setStringProperty("name", "value");
textMessage.setBooleanProperty("i_am_a_header", true);
// etc
```